# Unable to import a custom DLL in python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, boost-python, python-c-api

I am trying to expose a C++ class to python with `boost::python`, so I am going through [this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/exposing.html). I created a visual studio `.dll` project, with this source code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

struct World
{
    void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set)
    ;
}
```

And I built it as a 64-bit dll. The next step in the tutorial says:

> Here, we wrote a C++ class wrapper that exposes the member functions greet and set. Now, after building our module as a shared library, we may use our class World in Python. Here's a sample Python session:

```
>>> import hello
>>> planet = hello.World()
>>> planet.set('howdy')
>>> planet.greet()
'howdy'
```

However, after launching python in the same directory and typing `import hello` I get

```
>>> import hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'hello'
>>>
```

I have tried renaming the 'dll' files to `hello.dll`, and also copying *every* output file (`dll`, `exp`, `ilk`, `lib`, and `pdb`) to `%PYTHONPATH%\DLLs`, yet I am still unable to import the module into python.

Much googling brought me to [this article](http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/articles/dll-in-c-for-python/) recommending I use `ctypes` to import the `dll`. This lets me load the `dll`, but I am still unable to call the "World" class. For example:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> mydll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("hello")
>>> mydll
<CDLL 'hello', handle 7fef40a0000 at 0x775ba8>
>>> hello = mydll.World()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 360, in __getatt
r__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __getite
m__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'World' not found
>>>
```

So a couple questions:

1. Is it possible to import a `dll` in python *without* using ctypes? The tutorial seems to indicate that it is, but doesn't provide very much detail about the right way to get the dll into python.
2. Which files do I need and where? It seems like I should only need the `dll` file from visual studio in the working directory of my python shell, but this is clearly not working for me.
3. Why can't I call `World` through ctypes?

Some more important details: I am using windows 7 64-bit, python 3.5.2 64-bit, and Visual Studio 2015 with Boost 1.61.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually just figured out the answer shortly after posting the question. Thanks to [this blog post](http://mmmovania.blogspot.com/2013/01/running-c-code-from-python-using.html) I found out that simply renaming the `hello.dll` to `hello.pyd` was enough. From some more googling, I *think* that `ctypes` is only for C DLLs, not C++, and *not* with boost!. The point of `boost::python`, is to remove the need for ctypes and make the DLL compatible with python. So to answer all of my own questions:

1. Yes, but it must have a `.pyd` extension.
2. You only need the compiled `dll` file and the `boost_python_vc140...dll` (may vary). However, like I said, the `dll` file must be renamed.
3. Because ctypes is not the right tool for loading a `boost::python` dll!

Comment: for anyone finding this answer, also have a look at pybind11