# Dependency errors when loading custom dll in python, built with Visual Studio 2017 and boost

Tags: python, c++, boost, dll, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build the [BGSLibrary](https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary) python module from C++ and boost source. The library compiles without a problem on linux. For windows I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Cmake 3.9. Here were my steps.

1. Visual Studio Install options 
   [image]
2. Download Boost, Install Script from within Visual Studio Command Line Terminal

   `bootstrap.bat`

   `b2 -j%cores% toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=32 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static --build-type=complete stage --with-python`

   3. Rename boost_python-vc141-mt-s-1_64.lib to python_boost.lib to satisfy cmake requirements.
3. CMake Config options
   [image]
4. Visual Studio External Include Directories
   [image]
5. Visual Studio External Lib Directories
   [image]
6. Move a copy of the originally named boost_python-vc141-mt-s-1_64.lib to the bgs build folder.
7. Execute Visual Studio Build. It successful creates libbgs python dll
   [image]
8. According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354389/unable-to-import-a-custom-dll-in-python) I rename libbgs.dll to .pyd and have the boost lib in the folder. I added bgslibrary/build to path. Unfortunately not quite there yet.

[image]

Some dependency issue. A quick look at DependencyWalker is very intimidating, a huge number of problems.

[image]

Before I go and try to individual add all those .dll manually to the bgslibrary/build folder, is there a higher level error that I've done. Should I have selected "static library" in the general properties of visual studio, would that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Dependency walker is old enough where it just shows alot of errors. Really it was jut the 4 opencv dlls. Adding opencv/build/release/bin to my path did it.